# Преобразование Хафа для окружности на Java (Hough transformation)

Tags: java

Прошу помощи по преобразованию Хафа. 
Теорию с википедии читал, так же читал Хабру на эту тему, но все примеры в основном для прямой.

Цель программы: занимаюсь пулевой стрельбой и обучению программирования на Java. Стреляю по бумажке, и необходимо по фотографии определить точки попадания, СТП (средняя точка попадания) , определить в какой сектор все улетатает и т.п.

Формулу для создания аккумуляторного массива я видел, но к сожалению, в голове все не собирается в единую картинку.

Примерно представляю себе следующий алгоритм действий, для подготовки картинки к поиску кругов:

1. Обесцветить
2. Бинаризировать
3. Определить грани
4. Пройтись по картинке алгоритмом Хафа для составления аккумуляторного массива

Бинаризацию удалось победить:

[image: бинаризированно изображение]

А вот что делать дальше к сожалению не могу понять, подскажите пожалуйста код или примеры на Java которые объясняют или показывают, как можно найти центры моих окружностей (хотя бы большой и жирной центральной).

P.S. Знаю что есть OpenCV, но так как я обучаюсь то хочется это сделать полусамостоятельно.

Answer (score 0):

Тут всё достаточно просто. Лучше работать с исходным изображением. Отверстия имеют другой цвет. Просто сначала удали всё на изображении что не имеет подобный диапазон цвета, потом уже бинаризируй. Получиться должно изображение с 5-ю точкам, эти точки находи по заданному радиусу преобразованием Хафа. Далее накладываешь данные точки на исходное изображение с изменения цвета на красный и всё=). Все попадания будут выделяться красным=)